# How to group by and get latest record in group contain all of fields in Django?

Tags: python, jquery, django, group-by, django-annotate

Imagine we have a table like this:

| id | name | type | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | male | 2022-03-02 |
| 2 | Jane | female | 2022-04-02 |
| 3 | Kirk | male | 2022-03-04 |
| 4 | Sarah | female | 2022-04-04 |
| 5 | Jason | male | 2022-03-05 |

And i want to *group by* type and just get latest records based on `created_at`.
So i tried this code and not bad:

```
result = User.objects.values('type').annotate(
            latest_date=Max('created_at'),
)
```

When print the **result** i face to this:

```
<QuerySet [
{'type': 'male', 'latest_date': '2022-03-05'}, 
{'type': 'female', 'latest_date': '2022-04-04'}
]>
```

My question is: Where is other fields `id` and `name`?
I expect to get:

```
<QuerySet [
{id: 5, name: 'Jason', 'type': 'male', 'latest_date': '2022-03-05'}, 
{id: 4, name: 'Sarah', 'type': 'female', 'latest_date': '2022-04-04'}
]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `order_by` with `distinct`

```py
User.objects.order_by("type", "-created_at").distinct("type")
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
result = User.objects.values('type').annotate(
                latest_date=Max('created_at'),
    ).values('id','name','type','latest_date')
```

Comment: When use values give me 5 records as result.